# Javascript: change button text after click. event.target doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5k38svc9/1/

I have a button. When clicked, a form is appended to the document. That works fine. However I also need the button to change its text, but can't achieve it:

```
<div class = "video-row">


    <div class="video-buttons">
    <div class="add-button green-button light-button">Add comedian to favourites</div>

  <form style="display:none" id = "the-form" action="/login" method="post">
         <h2 class="form-title">Login</h2>
         <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
         <button class = "login light-button" type="submit">Send</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

```
var addForm = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("the-form");
    element.style.display = "block";
    var button = $(event.target);
    button.innerHTML = "Hide form";
}


var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("add-button");
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', addForm, false);
}
```

Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: Remove the jQuery wrapper around `event.target` in `addForm`, or alternatively do `button.text('Hide form')`, currently you're mixing jQuery and native `innerHTML`. Also, you should not use the non-standard global `event` object, add the object to the argument list of the function definition instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `addForm` to this:

```
var addForm = function(event) {
    var element = document.getElementById("the-form");
    element.style.display = "block";
    var button = event.target;
    button.innerText = "Hide form";
}
```

Basically in the snippet you don't have jQuery so you can't use it, also you are not passing event object to the event handler `addForm`, finally I used `.innerText()` instead of `innerHTML()` since you are replacing the text only.

here is a working snippet:

```js
var addForm = function(event) {
    var element = document.getElementById("the-form");
    element.style.display = "block";
    var button = event.target;
    button.innerText = "Hide form";
}


var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("add-button");
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', addForm, false);
}
```

```css
.video-row  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;

}

.video-buttons  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.light-button {
   padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class = "video-row">
    

    <div class="video-buttons">
    <div class="add-button green-button light-button">Add comedian to favourites</div>

  <form style="display:none" id = "the-form" action="/login" method="post">
         <h2 class="form-title">Login</h2>
         <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
         <button class = "login light-button" type="submit">Send</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution may help your cause:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunc()" id="myBtn">Press this Button</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").textContent;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```